# Progress bar with 'text-inside' attribute CSS

Tags: html, css, element-ui

Can someone help me with the following `progress` element of `Element UI` library:
[Element UI - Progress link](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/progress)

I'm trying to reach for this result:
[image]
put the value at the end of each bar

Currently, having this:
[image]
with the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<el-progress :text-inside="true" :percentage="item.value" color="#6A7EC7" :stroke- 
width="12"></el-progress>
```

**CSS:**

```
.el-progress-bar__outer {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
```

I've tried to do put the text div as `relative` like the following:

```
  >>> .el-progress-bar__innerText {
      color: $color-tremor-black;
      position: relative;
      left: 30px;
  }
```

But the text is being cut when the value is close to the end.
[image]

What I'm missing? need to do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to remove this component and build my own progress bar by using div and CSS.
Like the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="newProgress">
  <div class="progressBar" :style="{width:`${item.value}%`}"></div>
  <span class="newProgressValue">{{item.value}}%</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.newProgress {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 400px;
}

.progressBar {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 3px 0px 0px 10px;
  background: #6A7EC7;
  border: 1px solid #6A7EC7;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.newProgressValue {
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-size: $font-size-small-plus;
}
```

I've couldn't find some information about `Element UI` library and its styles.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using ::v-deep to access the inner child of the class

```
::v-deep .el-progress-bar__inner {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```